# i am trying to plot "scatter" on top of "imagesc" which dosen't work.

Tags: matlab

i am trying to plot "scatter" on top of "imagesc" which dosen't work. However, i can plot "scatter" figure separately. I even tried "hold all" instead of "hold on". Can someone help me out? Thank you.

```
figure(2)
imagesc(lat1,height,scatter0')
hold on;
scatter(lat1,top2,'k')
title('2012_12_4')
colormap(colors)
axis xy
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is probably x-y limits that are not matched, or that the z-values that are not properly normalized to plot side by side. The normalization is important because `imagesc` and `scatter` will share the same colormap. Other than that, your code works nicely for me. For example, I'm normalizing in the range [0,1] the "z" values of both plots:

```
load seamount
m=peaks(200);
m=(m-min(m(:)))./(max(m(:))-min(m(:)));
imagesc([0.996 1.0005],[1,1.012],m); 
hold on ; 

z=(z-min(z(:)))./(max(z(:))-min(z(:)));
scatter(x./max(x(:)),y./max(y(:)),5,z);
```

[image]